# Ruby's GServer only wants to work on localhost

Tags: ruby, sockets

TCPServer.new(port) creates a server that can service requests from localhost or remote machines.

But GServer.new(port) creates a server that can only service requests from localhost.

In looking at GServer's source, it calls TCPServer.new(@host,@port).  @host defaults to DEFAULT_HOST which is 127.0.0.1.

The source for TCPServer.new says:

```
# TCPServer.new([hostname,] port) => tcpserver
# Creates a new server socket bound to _port_.
# If _hostname_ is given, the socket is bound to it.
```

I would like to use GServer, but not bind to a certain host name.  Is such a thing possible?  Every example on the web uses only localhost.

It seems that if no host is specified to GServer, GServer should not specify a host to TCPServer.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - I ran into the same problem.  Is there a way to override DEFAULT_HOST to 0.0.0.0 (that is, make a sweeping change without changing the code which calls GServer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `0.0.0.0` for your hostname to bind to all interfaces.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't see this documented anywhere.

Comment: Glad that worked.  It may not be in the documentation, but binding to 0.0.0.0 is the typical way to do this (it's also how most services will bind if you look at services listening on your computer with `netstat` or similar tools).