# How to set GServer DEFAULT_HOST?

Tags: ruby, localhost

**Background:** I'm using a ruby gem called [bane](http://blog.danielwellman.com/2010/09/introducing-bane-a-test-harness-for-server-connections.html) which in turn uses [GServer](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/gserver/rdoc/classes/GServer.html) to listen for HTTP connections.

According to [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662403/rubys-gserver-only-wants-to-work-on-localhost), by default GServer uses the `DEFAULT_HOST` when listening, which is set to `127.0.0.1`.

**Problem:** I want bane to listen on `0.0.0.0` (that is, all incoming connections, not just from locallhost). Rather than hack bane's source to allow an IP address to be specified, is there a way to override the default host in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

**1) Override the GServer constant**

In case you're not using GServer for anything else, then this approach will give you `0.0.0.0` globally.

```
GServer.send(:remove_const, "DEFAULT_HOST")
GServer::DEFAULT_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
```

**2) Monkey patch Bane**

```
# Something like this perhaps?
module Bane
  class BehaviorServer < GServer
    def initialize(port, behavior, options = {})
      super(port, options[:default_host] || GServer::DEFAULT_HOST)
      @behavior = behavior
      @options = options
      self.audit = true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up hacking option #1 into bin/bane.